# Call method which returns an array in v-for and iterate through it in vue.js

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js

I am looking for the best practice to do this.
Inside the v-for loop I need to call a method which lazy loads data from associated model. But how to do it in best practice?

```
<div v-for="speaker in allSpeaker" :key="speaker.id" class="d-sm-flex mt-8 align-start">
      // here i call that method
      {{ const programs = await speaker.getPrograms() }}
          <li v-for="program in programs"...
       /// probably bad practice!
                <v-img
                    v-if="!!speaker.image"
                    class="white--text mx-auto mr-sm-3 ml-sm-0 mb-5 mb-sm-0"
                    aspect-ratio="1"
                    :src="speaker.image"
                    :srcset="speaker.image.set"
                />
                <div v-else class="image-replacer mx-auto mr-sm-3 ml-sm-0 mb-5 mb-sm-0">&nbsp;</div>
                <div>
                    <div class="">
                        <p>{{speaker.firstname + ' ' + speaker.lastname}}</p>
                        <p>{{speaker.organisation}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="py-4">{{speaker.description}}</div>
                </div>
```

I commented above what I want to do. And am looking for best practice here

Answer (score 0):

`{{ const programs = await speaker.getPrograms() }}`
This should not be on your template.

I would try a lifecycle method like :

```
async init() {
    this.allSpeakers = await getSpeakers()
    this.programs = this.allSpeakers.map(speaker => speaker.getPrograms())

}
```

In your template you should have a `v-if="programs"` for your programs and also for your allSpeakers in order to wait fetching the data and then render